# How can I get noWrap to work in a Typography component nested inside an Alert/ AlertTitle component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to get a `Typography` component to properly truncate overflowing text with an ellipsis, but it does not work when it is nested inside an `Alert` component. Here is a sample snippet of what I have:

```
<MenuItem>
  <Alert style={{ width: 300 }}>
    <AlertTitle>
      <Typography variant="inherit" noWrap>
        Here is my text.
      </Typography>
    </AlertTitle>
  </Alert>
</MenuItem>
```

According to the documentation for MaterialUI v4 (which I am using), the `noWrap` attribute only works on block or inline elements. I've tried adding the attribute to the `Alert`, `AlertTitle`, and `Typography` components, but none seem to properly truncate the text. I could style the menu items to look like an `Alert` so that I don't need to nest the `Typography` inside of the `Alert`s, but if possible I'd prefer to keep the structure above if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v5 of Material-UI your code works just fine. To make it work the same in v4 you need to make two adjustments:

- Specify `component="p"` on the `Typography` element. In v4 it defaults to "span" which doesn't support `noWrap`
- Specify `overflow: "auto"` for the [`message` CSS class](https://v4.mui.com/api/alert/#css) within `Alert`

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import AlertTitle from "@material-ui/lab/AlertTitle";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  alert: {
    "& .MuiAlert-message": {
      overflow: "auto",
    },
  },
}));

export default function SimpleAlerts() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Alert style={{ width: 300 }} className={classes.alert}>
      <AlertTitle>
        <Typography variant="inherit" noWrap component="p">
          Here is my text and now it is getting too long to fit.
        </Typography>
      </AlertTitle>
    </Alert>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/alert-typography-nowrap-w5768q?file=%2Fdemo.js%3A1%2C1-28%2C1